# Autocheck all checkboxes within dynamic html div

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I want to check all the check-boxes within a html div if the "parent checkbox" for that div is checked. I'm new at JavaScript/PHP/HTML. Can anyone provide an useful explanatory example?

Here's my code:

```
<form>
  <?php
    while(list($k, $v)=each($Aff))
    {
    if ($k == 0)
    {
      array_push($parentAff, substr($v, 0, 2));
      $substring = $v;
      echo ('<div id ="Div'.$v.'">');
    }
    if ((substr($substring, 0, 2) != substr($v, 0, 2)) && (strlen($substring) != 1))
    {
      echo ('</div>');
      echo ('<div id ="'.$v.'">');
      array_push($parentAff, substr($v, 0, 2));
      $counter++;
      $substring = $v;
      echo "<hr>";
    }

    echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="Aff[]" id="'.$v.'" value="'.$v.'" /><label for="text'.$k.'">'.$v.'</label>');


    $substring = $v;

    }

    echo ('</div>');

  ?>
</form>
```

The number of checkboxes within a div depend on what data comes out of the database to the array Aff[]. The parent checkbox for each div would be the one in the parentAff array which is identified by the div id.

Comment: Do you want to select the children checkboxes when the user clicks the parent checkbox or did you want them checked on load?

Comment: when checking the parent box i also want the children to become checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following code pen for an example of how to accomplish this using JS.

https://codepen.io/psmith104/pen/gByKzx

I've also included the code here as well.

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" /> Parent Checkbox
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Child 1
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Child 2
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Child 3
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Child 4
</div>
```

And here is the JS

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox].parent").forEach(function(parent) {
    parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:not(.parent)").forEach(function(child) {
            child.checked = true;
        });
    });
});
```